# Failure to extract correct contents using re.findall() with python

Tags: python, regex, findall

I am using Python 2 and I have a string

```
c = """
if ( is.data.frame(by) && ncol(by)>1 ) { by_by = sapply( by, paste.me, collapse, split) }
  ldat = sapply(xdat, by_by )
  out = data.table::rbindlist( lapply(ldat, FUN, ...) )
  return(out)
"""
```

I'd like to extract the second argument within either sapply() or lapply() and hence expect to get `['paste.me','by_by','FUN']`. Unfortunately, I get `['split', 'by_by', '...']` using the following code.

```
re.findall(r"\b[sl]apply\(.+,\s*([\w._]+?)[,\s)]", c)
```

I already used the non-greedy qualifier `?`. Why it is still going for the longest pattern without stopping at the second `,`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble is that the `.+` is slurping up the first comma, you should change it to `.+?`, or better yet, `[^,]+`

Comment: I see it's the other place I forgot to add the non-greedy qualifier.